# when i installed the tinder react card and wanted to access the page this error pops up

Tags: reactjs

[Error that happens when i start my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9pDc.png)
my project consists of making a dating app for cats and i tried to clone a tinder page but add my own touch to it with a different database and different informations on the user

```
import TinderCard from 'react-tinder-card'
import { useState } from 'react'

const Dashboard = () => {
    const characters = [
        {
            name: 'Richard Hendricks',
            url: './img/richard.jpg'
        },
        {
            name: 'Erlich Bachman',
            url: './img/erlich.jpg'
        },
        {
            name: 'Monica Hall',
            url: './img/monica.jpg'
        },
        {
            name: 'Jared Dunn',
            url: './img/jared.jpg'
        },
        {
            name: 'Dinesh Chugtai',
            url: './img/dinesh.jpg'
        }
    ]
    const [lastDirection, setLastDirection] = useState()

const outOfFrame = (name) => {
    console.log(name + ' left the screen!')
}



return (
    <div className="dashboard">
     
        <div className="swiper-container">
            <div className="card-container">
                {characters.map((character) =>
                    <TinderCard className='swipe' key={character.name} onSwipe={(dir) => swiped(dir, character.name)} onCardLeftScreen={() => outOfFrame(character.name)}>
                        <div style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + character.url + ')' }} className='card'>
                            <h3>{character.name}</h3>
                        </div>
                    </TinderCard>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}
export default Dashboard

i searched around for an answer but i couldnt find anything help